# PHP delete elements in associate array by value

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove integers in array less than X with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619944/remove-integers-in-array-less-than-x-with-php)

```
$array = array( 
    "a" => 10, 
    "b" => 9, 
    "c" => 8, 
    "d" => 7,
    "e" => 6,
    "f" => 5,
    "g" => 4,
    "h" => 3 
    );
```

How can I dele the item if the value is smaller than 6? i.e., how can I get the following array?

```
$array = array( 
    "a" => 10, 
    "b" => 9, 
    "c" => 8, 
    "d" => 7,
    "e" => 6
    );
```

Comment: Use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) and an [`if`](http://php.net/if) comparison, then [`unset`](http://php.net/unset) for unsetting them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter) is perfect for this:

```
$new = array_filter($old,function($a) {return $a >= 6;});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple iteration would be:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($arras as $key => $value){
  if($value >= 6)new_array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $index=>$value) {
  if ( $value < 6) {
    unset($array[$index]);
  }
}
```

or

```
foreach($array as $index=>$arr_value) {
  if ( $value >= 6) {
    $new_array[$index] = $arr_value;
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean `=>` instead of `->`. The latter is for accessing object properties/methods.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. Just out of shower, my brain still ain't working fine with details :)