# PHP - Get array value that isnt greater than the next array value

Tags: php, arrays

In this array:
`$array = array(6, 20, 50, 80, 100);`,

I want to return the value that hasn't passed a certain number.

For Example, lets say I have a number `$number = 45;`. I want to return `20` from the `$array`.

... and if i have a number `$number = 99;`, I want to return 80.

If the number is `$number = 20;`, only then would it return 20.

How can i accomplish this?

EDIT: Sorry for not including example code... It was a simple question I assumed.

Basically this was solved with the accepted answer below.

Comment: How have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: It's a simple foreach task with storing previous value.

Comment: As with most questions on SO, if you at least show what you have tried you will get a much better response from the community

Comment: What did you tried so far? This is very basic foreach loop with store of value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove integers in array less than X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619944/how-to-remove-integers-in-array-less-than-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through every item in your array, and for each item that is lower than your number,  replace a variable with that number.

```
    $final = 0;
    foreach($array as $element) {
        if($element <= $number) {
            $final = $element;
        }
    }
```

If your array is not in order, it should be done a bit differently.

```
$final-array = array();
    foreach($array as $element) {
        if($element <= $number) {
            array_push($final-array, $element);
        }
    }
$final = 0;
foreach($final-array as $num) {
    if($num>$final) {
        $final = $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me out

Comment: Why not simply `sort` the array?

Answer (score 4):

You could first [rsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) the array and then loop until the value is lower or equal then the value you specify and then [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) out of the loop because there is no need anymore to continue.

```
$value = 99;
$array = array(6, 20, 50, 80, 100);
rsort($array);
$result = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a <= $value) {
        $result = $a;
        break;
    }
}

echo $result; //80
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CqE9W)

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think that would work.  This would give the value one above what he wants, what I would do is put the $result = $a after the if statement, and only include the break in the if statement.

Comment: @KevinLewis I have updated that to rsort and switched the operator.